# UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

trying to make animation on google colab.

getting this warning: **UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable**

**warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)**

did *pip install ffmpeg-normalize*  but no use.

How to deal with this?

Comment: You may need to install ffmpeg first. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634997/how-do-i-properly-enable-ffmpeg-for-matplotlib-animation).